# How to force a non-breaking line with a thin space

Tags: epub

I am looking to make a space between to characters non-breaking line...

Here is a demo of what I am talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/hGdXE/1/

I have also tried this:

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span>
```

The problem is that this code does not work in Kobo eBook readers.

Is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

There are basically [four approaches](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/french.html) in general to the issue of non-breaking thin space: 1) Use U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE, which would be a purely character-level solution, but browser and font support is a problem. 2) Use U+2009 THIN SPACE and try to make it non-breaking, as you have tried. This mostly works, but it is clumsy, and you would need to include characters from each side of the thin space, as in your fiddle. 3) Use a normal space, U+0020 SPACE, and try to make it both non-breaking and suitably narrow with the use of CSS. 4) Use U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE and try to make it narrow with CSS.

The last approach seems to be the best shot in general. You would need to wrap the no-break space in an inline element and set its `display` property to `inline-block`, so that `width` setting will have an effect:

```
<span class=fine>&nbsp;</span>
```

with CSS code like

```
.fine {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.125em;
}
```

I hope this works with Kobo ebook reader. It should, since the no-break space is generally well supported in browsers, with just some exceptions in IE, and the CSS styling is simple.

Comment: Option one was tried and did not work. Option 2, like you said I tried and it failed in Kobo. Option 3 I am not sure how you can do that. Option 4 was also tried and failed. And your last approach does not work ether. It seems to me that they're is no solution to this problem.

Comment: It would be relevant to know how the approaches failed, and perhaps see the exact code you tried. There was no last approach after the 4th; the sample code illustrates the 4th approach.

Comment: I tried this: <span class="fine">&nbsp;</span> with: .fine {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.125em;
}

Comment: I also tried: <span style="word-spacing:-0.13em">mark&nbsp;!</span> but the word-spacing does not seem to work.

Comment: The way it failed? after the « there was a line break.

Comment: For this one: <span style="word-spacing:-0.13em">mark&nbsp;!</span> the space was to large. It seems that word-spacing does not work in Kobo.